# Single word to denote both request and receipt

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever I am ordering components for some project I put them in a project tracker. A line might be like:

```
Order and Receive 5 Boxes
```

or

```
Request and Pick up the Check
```

When writing code to do networking you also have this problem. You have some code to "request" some data, and then you have code to handle what happens if the data doesn't come through. But on top of that there is a function that hides all that complexity and just "____"s the data.

**Obtain, requisition, and acquire** are all decent solutions to this problem. The problem is that they don't explicitly contain within them the idea that *the task is both started and completed within the scope of this single word*.

Requisition is much more like a request that has a high probability of success. Obtain and acquire certainly have a connotation of success and completion, but without the idea of the process that precedes them.

Those words are also a bit erudite.

Compound words are probably fine as long as they are normal use. Phrases are less good but maybe ok.

I have taken to using the made up word *carg* for this (because to me it sounds a bit like both cargo and the Spanish word *encargar*, which means to place in charge). But it turns out you can't expect others to know your private made up words.

Any other ideas? :)

Comment: I find your question unclear. Under what circumstances can you guarantee to both place an order and receive it? These are independent acts by different agents. You might order and then not receive. P.S. are you asking about coding or are you asking about everyday language?  If coding, then normally a function just "processes" the data.

Comment: I’m talking about both in every day language and in programming. If the programming context is unclear just ignore it. You never just order something. Instead, you come into contact with a vendor, indicate the item you would like to acquire, and remit funds in order for them to transfer the product to you, the final step of which requires them to package and ship the product. However, this entire sequence can be encapsulated by the single word “order“. I would like to have a word that encapsulates all of that process as well as its termination by successfully receive the product

Comment: I suggest that you simply "complete" the action, e.g. "complete order". Or you can "process" the action, e.g. "process check". You can also process an order.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I'm not too sure about 'complete' and 'process' in this case. Both those terms, to me, describe what the vendor does, not what the customer does.

Comment: I don't think you will find a word that unambiguously describes what both the vendor and customer do as a joint activity.

Comment: I'd use *get* and be done with it. The computer has to understand, not my English teacher.

Comment: It is less than clear why you reject *obtain*. Surely, if one has obtained something, it is obvious that one has performed whatever steps were necessary to obtain it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Honestly I think *get* might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Procured - implicit that something was requisitioned, ordered and received.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procure

Definition of procure
1transitive : to get possession of (something) : to obtain (something) by particular care and effort

Answer (score 0):

Fulfillment or fulfillment process come to mind.